# Show / Hide table row based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of four radio buttons that represent four different conditions (Good, Improving, Worsening, Poor).  Selecting "worsening" or "poor" should unhide a table row with a textarea to explain why the condition is not good.  Selecting "good" or "improving" should hide the table row.  I've tried adding a class to the two that unhide the table row, but only one of the buttons is working (worsening).  I have a feeling I need an or clause in there somewhere to pickup both buttons, but I've tried many variations and I'm just not coming up with it.  Appreciate any help for this noob.

Here is what I have:

```
<tr>
     <td>
      Customer Sentiment:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
    <div id="sentiment">
        <input class="xhide" type="radio" id="Good" value="1"   name="sentimentID" <cfif sentimentID eq 1>checked</cfif> /><label for="Good">Good</label>
        <input class="xhide" type="radio" id="Improving" value="2" name="sentimentID" <cfif sentimentID eq 2>checked</cfif> /><label for="Improving">Improving</label>
        <input class="xshow" type="radio" id="Worsening" value="3" name="sentimentID" <cfif sentimentID eq 3>checked</cfif> /><label for="Worsening">Worsening</label>
        <input class="xshow" type="radio" id="Poor" value="4"   name="sentimentID" <cfif sentimentID eq 4>checked</cfif> /><label for="Poor">Poor</label>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>                        

<tr class="rnotes"">
    <td valign="top">Sentiment Notes:</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <cfoutput>
        <textarea   name="sentimentNotes"
                    cols="100"
                    rows="4">#sentimentNotes#</textarea>
        </cfoutput>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".rnotes").hide();

    $(':radio').change(function(){
    var isChecked=$('.xshow').prop('checked');
    $('.rnotes').toggle(isChecked);
    });
});
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".rnotes").hide();

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        var isShow = $(this).hasClass('xshow');
        $(".rnotes").toggle(isChecked && isShow);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LnyJZ/5/